# I need to generate a pop up window from server side in asp.net web api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, popup

I have a Asp.net web api, I need to show user a pop up in case some information is not valid. How would I do that?

The server is a web api, so there is no view to add the javascript code there, So i need to generate the js code from code behind in server. Generally how can we show a pop up to user from client side without modifying the view?

```
[Route("api/entity/SaveConfiguration")]
[HttpPut]
public void SaveConfiguration(string data){
...
var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page; 
var Ob = FileList.Where(x => x.UserDefinedName == configurationFileName).FirstOrDefault();
if (!(Ob ==  {null)) {
string pg = "Test";
page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", string.Format("ShowPopup('{0}');", pg), true);
...
}
```

Note: The code above doesn't show the pop up

Comment: Do you have any code? This question is far too broad.

Comment: I did the modifications, The question is pretty clear! How can I show a pop up window in client side with out directly using javascript!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at what you are trying to do.

An API has a job, to receive requests and provide responses. Creating popups is not something that makes sense in the context of an API.

Clients using the API may not even the capability to deal with JavaScript. You can call an API from a console app, or a third party tool.

Providing information to a user regarding something that's missing, presumably some calling model properties, is done via a response, you issue a Bad Request with details why, expecting the user to fix their calling data and attempt the call again.